# Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1903951872) (tried to allocate 24 bytes)

Tags: php

I have a problem with this script php, I tried to change

```
memory_limit=2048M
```

and

```
upload_max_filesize=4096M
```

but it's not working.
I even put on the top script

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M'); and init_set('memory_limit','-1');
```

Comment: After changes in php ini did u restrt apache???

Comment: give us the code you are trying to run

Comment: For releasing memory use like that ini_set('memory_limit','-1'); but before set the memory

Comment: I resolved splitting the input file .txt